# Show that if $S \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ the int(S) is open, and that, if $U$ is any open subset of $S$, then $U \subseteq$ int(S).

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, proof-verification, proof-writing

Looking for feedback on my proof:

Let $A$ be all the open balls $\left\{ x|\exists r > 0 (B(x;r) \subseteq S \right\}$ in $S$. By definition int$(S) = A$ and since for all $x \in A$ there is an open ball $B(x;r)$, int$(S)$ is open. Now $U$ open $\implies U = \{x'|\exists r'>0 (B(x';r') \subseteq U)\}$. So for any $x'$ in $U, x' \in A$ since $A$ is all the open balls in $S$. But $A =$ int$(S)$ so $x' \in$ int$(S)$. Therefore $U \subseteq$ int$(S)$.

Answer (score 1):

Your $A$ is not a set of open balls but you called it one. You showed that $x\in int(S) \implies x\in int(S)$, but what you wanted to show was $x\in int(S) \implies x\in int(int(S))$. (I've seen this mistake a lot, a good exercise with a similar idea would be to show that $Cl(E)$ is closed for every $E$.)

The proof for the other implication has some mistakes that makes it hard to understand what you're trying to say. If $A$ is the set of all the open balls contained in $S$, the interior of $S$ is not $A$ but rather $\cup A$. (The union of all the elements of A.) Try to be more precise with your writing, and we can check your proof again.

Comment: I see your point for the first part. For the second, wouldn't the union of all the balls simply be the set S? It is only the interior points that make up the interior correct?

Comment: Check for example $[0,1]\subseteq\mathbb{R}$. No open ball contained in [0,1] contains $0$ or $1$. So if $A=\{ B \subseteq [0,1]:$ $B$ is an open ball $\}$. The union $\cup A$ is exactly $(0,1)$ or $int([0,1])$.